# Error: Cannot find module 'eslint-config-appium' while running ./Scripts/bootstrap.sh

Tags: ios, webdriver-io, appium-ios

Getting error while running command `./Scripts/bootstrap.sh` under directory:
`/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent`

**Error StackTrace:**

```
Cannot find module 'eslint-config-appium'
Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/.eslintrc
Error: Cannot find module 'eslint-config-appium'
Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/.eslintrc
at ModuleResolver.resolve (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent/Inspector/node_modules/eslint/lib/util/module-resolver.js:74:19)
at resolve (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent/Inspector/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:515:25)
at load (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent/Inspector/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:532:26)
at configExtends.reduceRight (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent/Inspector/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:424:36)
at Array.reduceRight (native)
at applyExtends (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent/Inspector/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:408:28)
at Object.load (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent/Inspector/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-file.js:566:22)
at loadConfig (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent/Inspector/node_modules/eslint/lib/config.js:63:33)
at getLocalConfig (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent/Inspector/node_modules/eslint/lib/config.js:130:29)
at Config.getConfig (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent/Inspector/node_modules/eslint/lib/config.js:260:26)
```

Comment: It looks like you don't have that package installed. Is it present in your project's `package.json`? Go to `appium` (`/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium`) and install its dependencies via **npm install**. If not, try a `npm install eslint-config-appium` in your project root and retry, or install it globally in case you have a local issue: `npm install -g eslint-config-appium`.

Comment: Hi @iamdanchiv,
I followed the above steps and now `package.json` contains it
`{
  "name": "admin",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "eslint-config-appium": "^2.0.1",
    "wd": "^1.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },`

Comment: But getting this error:
`/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuitest-driver/WebDriverAgent/Inspector/js/app.js
  12:18  error  Unable to resolve path to module 'js/http'                import/no-unresolved
  15:18  error  Unable to resolve path to module 'js/tree'                import/no-unresolved
  16:22  error  Unable to resolve path to module 'js/tree_node'           import/no-unresolved
  17:25  error  Unable to resolve path to module 'js/tree_context'        import/no-unresolved
and so on.`

Comment: Well, frankly I can't be more verbose than that error you're getting now. `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/appium-xcuit‌​est-driver/WebDriver‌​Agent/Inspector/js/a‌​pp.js 12:18 error Unable to resolve path to module 'js/http`. This should be something you should be able to debug locally.

Comment: Thanks @iamdanchiv . Appreciate your help. I have opened a new issue for this error. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44409604/error-unable-to-resolve-path-to-module-js-http-js-tree-etc-on-running-s

Will update you once it is resolved.

Comment: @iamdanchiv The last error mentioned didn't create any problem in build and launch of browser. That was some other issue. However error related to 'eslint-config-appium' was resolved with your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: I'm glad it worked! Good job Aakash!